# How to extend internet coverage on this apt?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I'm a network novice, so please bear with me.

I want to extend internet coverage throughout the apartment, and I have no idea how to do it.

Our apartment looks more or less like the image below. The issue is that the concrete walls are thick at about 1', and there's a block of concrete (marked concrete) that's about 6x2 feet. The red indicates the electric outlets.

[image]

My question: how can I extend the internet from the modem to those rooms in the house? I was considering `wireless extenders`, but I have no idea how many I should buy given this layout, or if there are better alternatives.

Being the beginner that I am, What I did was connect a cable from the modem to the router. Then the PC that's the farthest away would be in the range, but just barely. The internet connection in that PC is very weak.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've handled far worse.

And its not that simple and depends on a lot of variables. Many modern routers seem to have *directional* flat antennae so  *how* you position your modem matters. You've seemingly handled the worst parts of the problem (that's an *excellent* position for a AP) though I'd try facing the *front* of the AP at the room with the worst reception. Its also worth doing your homework - I find certain brands work better than others (dlink for example, has always been an unmitigated disaster for me).

Its also worth remembering repeaters add to *signal congestion* - you'd want to find a less used, *non overlapping* channel for it. I'd try one at or just outside the room you have issues with. I just went with the cheapest one I could find, and tried plugpoints until I was happy with signal strength from both the router and the systems that needed to connect to it.

I've also run homeplug where I just couldn't get a reliable signal out. Its moderately finicky and has its own issues.